# Access same website with multiple sub names

Tags: asp.net, iis, web

I have developed an asp.net application. I will host the application as a new website in IIS.

I want the application to work like below,

1. http://localhost:81/firm1/login
2. http://localhost:81/firm2/login

All the above 3 calls need to hit my website and I will do some process with the names 'firm1', 'firm2'.

I don't want to create multiple websites/virtual applications or sub domains.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) in asp.net applications.

This will allow you to write modules that will receive the url of the requested page, break apart the url in components and delegate to your controllers from there.

If you already have routing set up, you will need to go through all the routes that need to sit below a 'Firm' and modify the URL they map to.  For example if you have

```
routes.MapPageRoute("LoginRoute", "/login", "~/login.aspx")
```

You would change that to

```
routes.MapPageRoute("LoginRoute", "/{FIRM_CODE}/login", "~/login.aspx")
```

The routing classes will parse out the first part of the URL and make it available inside your controller as

```
RouteData.values("FIRM_CODE")
```

From there you will need to modify all your logic to handle the firm specific behaviours.  You will probably want to store this value somwhere in your session state so that libraries have access to the current firm etc.

Comment: I already implemented routing in my application (/login, /account, etc...).

I have separate database for every firms. I will get the firm info from the url itself.

I just want multiple firms to use the single site/application, the firm will differentiate their experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirects from one domain to another by creating an on click event. But the best way to do it would be with Routing as mentioned in the previous answer. This is because hyperlinks generated using Routing does not require the changing of URL if the page changes its name or location.

Following this will help you to effectively use Routing:
1. Define custom URL patterns that are not dependent on physical file names.
2. Generate URLs based on route URL parameter values by using markup or code.
3. In a routed page, retrieve values passed in URL segments by using markup or code.

To add routes to a Web site, you can add them to the static Routes property of the RouteTable class by using the RouteCollection.MapPageRoute method.